# Accessing static properties of a pointer type

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, static, type-traits

I am trying to call a static method of a type in a tuple, but the tuple uses pointers, not the type itself. This means that when I use tuple_element I am getting a pointer type which I can not use to call the static method.

Does anyone know how to either convert a pointer type to its non-pointer equivalent, or access a static property of a pointer type?

```
struct Example
{
    static int example()
    {
        return 0;
    }
};

typedef Example* PointerType;

int main()
{
    PointerType::example(); // Nope
    (*PointerType)::example(); // Nope
    (typename *PointerType)::example(); // Nope
    (PointerType*)::example(); // Nope
}
```

Comment: Nope, that was merely an example i made up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [std::remove_pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_pointer) (since C++11) to get the type pointed to, e.g. (note `std::remove_pointer_t` is supported from C++14)

```
std::remove_pointer_t<PointerType>::example();
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems like exactly the right thing, i'll test it out and see if it works Edit: Yep, the compiler is recognising the type correctly. Thanks!

Comment: Its implementation is not complex; If you can't use C++11/C++14, making one by yourself would be easy.

Comment: It's implementation is 3 lines

Comment: @Nonanon Templates is powerful, in C++. :)